# Using 場合 with adjectives

Tags: grammar, particles

I was learning the uses of 場合は from japanesetest4you.com (in the sense "in the event of"), and couldn't help but notice that, although it behaves like a noun, its uses with adjectives were not listed. I've seen some examples where it is used with い-adjectives on tatoeba.org, so I just wanted to confirm nonetheless: is a constructions of the form 熱い場合 (if it is hot) correct? As for な-adjectives, which construction out of 静かな場合 and 静かの場合 (if it is quiet) is correct?

Comment: Yes, 場合 is often used like that, but keep in mind that while it can be used to express a condition, it can also just mean 'case' e.g. 熱い場合もある＝"there are cases where it's hot".

Comment: @Komet Thank you, I will keep that in mind. On a side-note, just to be explicit, I have edited the part of my question concerning な-adjectives.

Comment: Pure な-adjectives (like 静か) cannot be followed by の. Only 静かな場合 is correct.

Comment: @Komet I wanted to confirm because there are instances where a な-adjective is followed by some other modifying particle. For example, 「静かだそうだ」: "I heard it's quiet."

Comment: な adjectives only have な attached in the 連体形 (attributive form, where it's modifying a noun). They can be conjugated in various other ways for other grammatical constructions. https://www.kokugobunpou.com/%E7%94%A8%E8%A8%80/%E5%BD%A2%E5%AE%B9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E-2-%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8/

Comment: @Leebo Unfortunately, my knowledge of Kanji is not good enough to allow me to comprehend the linked content. Just to be clear, is 静か in the 連体形 here? Is 静かな場合 the correct construction?